# Java 11 or newer is required to run the IDE Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, java-11, android-studio-arctic-fox

When I try to update android studio to version: **Arctix Fox | 2020.3.0**
i get this error

```
Java 11 or newer is required to run the IDE,
Please contact support at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues
Your JRE: 1.8.0_301-b09x86 (Oracle Coporation)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre
```

Please note that i already have both installed even tho when i try to remove the old version 1.8 i get the same error.

my `JAVA_HOME` is set to: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12

and when i check java version in cmd using `java --version`
i get

```
openjdk 11.0.12 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.12+7 (build 11.0.12+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.12+7 (build 11.0.12+7, mixed mode)
```

---

**EDIT:**

if i delete folder jdk1.8.0_301 in path C:\Program Files (x86)\Java
i get this error:

```
Failed to load JVM DLL C:\Program
Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12\bin\jvm.dll
if you already have 32-bit JDK insalled, define a JAVA_HOME variablee in Computer > System Properties > System Settings > Environment Variables.
```

---

**EDIT:**

After removing all old versions than restarting pc and downloading and installing version JRE - 27 MB .msi, the error msg is gone when i try to open android studio but i got this new message says :

```
Cannot load a JDK class: com.sun.jdi.Field 
Please ensure you run the IDE on JDK rather than JRE.
```

Also i have noticed the new JAVA_HOME path is set to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\AdoptOpenJDK\jre-11.0.11.9-hotspot\
```

and when i try to change it to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk-11.0.12`

i get the same old error:

Failed to load JVM DLL C:\Program
Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12\bin\jvm.dll

Comment: Your java 8 was 32bit. Try installing a 32bit Java 11

Comment: java 11 doesnt have 32bit

Comment: Well, error seems to suggest it wants it - `if you already have 32-bit JDK insalled...`

Comment: And, there is https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot#x32_win

Comment: You can't use a JRE, as the error says

Comment: when i change the path from JRE to JDK i get error Failed to load JVM DLL C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12\bin\jvm.dll

Comment: 1) Does that DLL file actually exist? 2) There's an environment variable named `STUDIO_JDK` that you can try updating.

Comment: Did you properly uninstall Java 8 instead of just deleting it? Check if `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` is on the `PATH`, and remove it if necessary

Comment: @OneCricketeer after uninstalling java versions and jre than re downloading the version you linked it works now fine thanks

Comment: I was facing the same issue when I upgraded from the previous version of Android Studio, I had to reinstall the Android Studio after uninstalling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eventually i had to install new windows, after that all i had to do was to install android studio first before i install java or setup any environment and download fresh new SDK now everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

This is happening to me as well - when I open AS for fisrt time - all works, then I close it and try to open it again - I got same error. This looks like bug in AS, as it is magically resolved after reboot (even with java 8). I am at Windows 10